# Compare filename only for files 2 folder using FC

Tags: windows, cmd, compare, filenames, filecompare

i know the to compare files in 2 folder in window can use command 
fc [path A]* [path B]*

but if i want to compare filename only, what parameter i need to add or any other command in windows cmd prompt?

Comment: Please copy and paste the code you are trying to make work into the question. The answer depends on how you represent the file names.

Comment: None: The command __FC__ is designed for __File Contents__ compare. Open a command prompt window and run `fc /?` and output is the help for this command with all possible options. It looks like you want a list of files existing in both directories or a list of files existing only in directory A or B. In this case you have to compare the file listings of the directories and not the files in the directories A and B. Is there a reason for not using freeware or shareware applications like Total Commander, UltraCompare or Beyond Compare for a folder compare without having coding skills?

Answer (score 2):

to get differences (different file names) in two folders, you can use `robocopy`:

```
robocopy /L /mir "d:\tmp\first" "d:\tmp\second" /njh /njs /ns /ndl
```

`/L` does only list the files instead of copying. For the rest of the options, see `robocopy /?` (`/mir` to compare two folders, `/n*` to suppress unneeded information)